# Ubuntu: How to force default ACLs to take effect for newly created files/dirs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, access-control-list

I've created the following ACLs for a directory:

```
# file: .
# owner: www-data
# group: root
user::rwx
user:www-data:rwx
user:deploy:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-data:rwx
default:user:deploy:rwx
default:group::---
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

However, if a script creates a new directory and specifies a bitmask, the default mask isn't applied.

How can I force this ACL to take effect regardless of the bitmask that's supplied to mkdir()?

Comment: Could you provide some "getfacl" output form the parent directory, as well as the newly created subdirectory?

Comment: @tom maybe this link can help you http://serverfault.com/questions/556836/have-new-files-inherit-their-folders-extended-acls/557393#557393