# Have new files inherit their folder's extended ACLs

Tags: linux, gentoo, setfacl

We are moving our web files from AFS to a local volume with the acl flag set. We use extended ACLs for our permissions so users can edit different parts of our websites. In AFS, when you create a new file it inherits its parent's permissions.

How do we make it so that when users create new files in their web directories, those files inherit the parent's facl? (Which includes www-data) If it helps, we run Gentoo Linux.

Comment: what filesystem are you using in your local volume?

Comment: ext4 (with the acl flag in fstab)

Comment: if you check my answer you can see a link some example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Linux, many filesystems support posix acl.

If you have many directories and you want to apply the acls on subdirs

```
 -R, --recursive
       Apply operations to all files and directories recursively. This option cannot be mixed with ‘--restore’.
```

But if you want the acl are apply on files and directories on creation time, you need the defaults acls on directory

```
 setfacl -d -m user:user01:rwx dir
```

Comment: We are using posix/extended acls. What we want to do is have these apply recursively, as normal acls do, upon creation of a new file in that directory.

Comment: Alright, if new directories are created in the directory with default acls set will they also inherit those defaults? Or will the defaults apply at any depth?

Comment: yes, i tried now and i can tell it work, if you set the default acl on a directory, the subdir inherit the acl from parent dir and default too

Comment: Note that this will work for new or copied files, but *not for moved files*.  Moving keeps the existing ACLs, even if the destination has "default" ACLs set on it...

Answer (score 0):

Opening this here since I can't comment - the accept answer no longer works on Linux. Running it results in either `root@SmolLinuxBox:~# setfacl -d -m www-data:www-data:rwx /mnt/PrimaryDisk1/public_html/ setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 11` or `root@SmolLinuxBox:~# setfacl -d www-data:www-data:rwx -m /mnt/PrimaryDisk1/public_html Usage: setfacl [-bkndRLP] { -m|-M|-x|-X ... } file ... Try 'setfacl --help' for more information.`

I'd love to comment, but here I am.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/563179)